# Error renaming to MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, jboss, struts2, ear

I am curious about following error :

```
Publishing to JBoss 7.1 runtime server - MyEAP has encountered problem
Error renaming C:\(some path) to (MyEAR proj path)\(my war file)\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
you can change these settings in server etc...
```

I have created a simple EAR project along with a dynamic web project with stuts2. I am deploying EAR file and everything is working fine but whenever I make changes to any file and save I get this error message. What is the exact meaning of this message?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem to be that it is necessary to configure a scanner for external deployments.

See: ['Publishing to JBoss 7.1 Runtime Server...' has encountered a problem](https://developer.jboss.org/message/721701)

> In previous versions of JBossAS, there was an exposed JMX server with
>   an option to mark a folder as one that the deployment scanner should
>   look at.  This option still exists in AS7, but, we haven't integrated
>   with the management ability yet. THis means we can't do it on the fly,
>   currently, in the current toolset is a bit hurt by this missing
>   feature.
>
> It is still possible in the raw configuration of the server, howerver.
>   This means you can mark your server directly to scan some external folder by modifying 
>   your configuration and adding a deployment scanner. The instructions for it are over here:
>
> https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DeployingAnApplicationFromAnExternalDeploymentLocation
>
> To make use of this, double-click your jboss-7 server inside eclipse
>   to open the server editor. You can then switch over to the second
>   page, "Deployments", where you can change the deployment method to
>   "custom" and set any folder that's on the same filesystem as your
>   eclipse installation.  Once this is done, you can add that folder to
>   your server's deployment scanner lists as per the wiki above.